# Convert.ToInt32 - Keep Preceding Zero

Tags: c#

I have numbers stored in a database, and some have a zero as their first digit as they always need to be a certain amout of digits. I have a text box that has this number typed into it, so i do a Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text), which removes the starting zero if it has one. Does anyone have any ideas how i can keep the zero, or add it to the start after the convert?

Comment: If you want a leading zero, surely you don't want to convert to Int32? Why not keep it as a string?

Comment: i don't think that you can keep them. but you can format the converted int to show them again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Comment: @Matt Because the database type is an Int

Comment: @Grace - if the leading zeros are important, the database type should not be an int

Comment: So then the question turns into: how to add leading zeros to maintain a certain amount of digits when displaying an integer in a textfield.

Comment: @Richard: correction, if there are leading zeros, the database type *isn't* an int.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The only way to keep the preceding zeroes is to not convert it to a number.

A number doesn't have any preceding zeroes as it only contains the value, not the string representation of the value.

If you want to convert it to a number and then convert it back to a string, recreating the preceding zeroes, you can use a custom format:

```
string formatted = number.ToString("00000");
```

Or for a dynamic number of digits:

```
string formatted = number.ToString(new String('0', numberOfDigits));
```

Comment: +1 for explaining both options, because the best solution depends on the nature of the data (imo)

Comment: Isn't `number.ToString().PadLeft(numberOfDigits, '0')` easier? At least easier to read I would say... :)

Comment: I'm worried about negative values when doing padding like this. Example, your PadLeft option would look like this: "00-9" instead of -009.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to keep a padded zero, then keep the value as a String. Integers cannot keep information about padded zeros, since they simply represent a number.

If you need to validate the number entered, either use [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#overloads) or match the value against a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) (like `"^\d+$"`).

**Edit:** In addition to [Guffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040939/convert-toint32-keep-preceding-zero/2040968#2040968), you can use "D" ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString)) to format to a specified number of characters (with zero padding, if necessary):

```
string formatted = number.ToString("D5"); // 13 -> 00013
```

Comment: +1, for hinting about the Decimal ("D") format specifier. Since the question specifies `Convert.ToInt32()`, this is my personal preferred method of padding the value.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is when the number is put back into the database instead of feeding it an `int` use a `string` by using `myint.ToString("0000000")`.  With the number of 0's being the total length of the padded number.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work.

```
123.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'); // 00123
```

Comment: As commented on Svish's comment, this would create strange results with negative integers.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the string format for keep the leading zero:

```
int fooValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text)
//operations with foo Value
string formatValue = fooValue.ToString("#0000");
```