# formatting string to a number

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am parsing a string with text and numbers in it e.g. abc00123.

When i extract numbers 00123 it is still a string so i cast to a double.

After i do this it it loses the zeros at the beginning of this.

Also the length of the numbers can vary.

Is there anyway to keep the zero when casting the string to a double ?

if not maybe i will compare the two strings and if the size of the original array is bigger append the differences onto the beginning of the number if possible?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The data is stored in binary and it doesn't make sense for integer to have leading zero's. In case you need to present the data or do string manipulation you can format the data with Padding.

Comment: what number on earth is 00123? That ain't a number, although 123 exists and that is a number.

Comment: Very unclear what your actual goal is - please [edit] post to clarify. Also while editing demonstrate that you've searched for similar problems (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040939/convert-toint32-keep-preceding-zero) and explain how it did not work in your case.

Comment: The datatype `double` does not have any information on "leading" zeros before a decimal point or on "trailing" zeros after a decimal point. Mathematically there is an infinite number of each. Outputting the data that represents a "double" number to your screen or a text file means taking that *number* and representing it as a *string*, when doing this you can choose how many leading or trailing zeros to display. Once you have a `double` you have to specifically add in zeros when outputting the double as string. E.g., see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No.  A double does not understand anything about the formatting of the number-- only the number itself.  123, 0123, and 00123 are all the same value when stored as a double.  You have to convert it back to a string if you want it formatted.

To illustrate:

```
var testString = "00123";
var testDouble = double.Parse(testString);

Console.WriteLine(testDouble.ToString());   //would return 123
Console.WriteLine(testDouble.ToString("00000")); //would return 00123
Console.WriteLine(testDouble.ToString("000000"));   //would return 000123
```

Answer (score 0):

Well doubles can not have zeros in their left hand side as its actually meaningless. But you can compare them as string as you said. for those which vary in length you can use `PadLeft` to just make them all the same length:

`sepratedNumber.PadLeft(10,'0')`; this will append as many zeros to the left side of the variable `sepratedNumber` till its total length equals 10.